# How is the duplicity URL for Deja-Dup's UbuntuOne storage constructed?

Tags: ubuntu-one, deja-dup, duplicity

I'm using Deja-Dup to store my backups from multiple systems to my UbuntuOne subscription.  I have setup weekly backups that should be keep at least 28 days.  Yet it seems that Deja-Dup will keep the backups longer.  I wish I could configure Deja-Dup to run duplicity's "duplicity remove-all-but-n-full" every time a backup completes with a configurable 'n'.  I was now going to write a cronjob to do that as a workaround.  But that command needs a URL probably with credentials.  But I have no idea where to find the URL for the UbuntuOne storage.  I have found some indication that scheme must be something like "u1+https://user@some.server/some/path" but I have no idea how to construct the URL for my account and how to add the account credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [duplicity documentation](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html#toc20):

> Duplicity expects the token in the environment variable `FTP_PASSWORD` (in the format "`consumer_key:consumer_secret:token:token_secret`").

The [URL Format documentation](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html#toc8) suggests the url should take the form `u1://host_is_ignored/volume_path`